i have the code which is working in a spacific range , i need move value ranfance and proide output acordingly
below is the code i need to work in all below range till end the value available
i have the code which is working in a specific range , i need move value ranfance and proide output accordingly.
Sub CTC_Code()
Sheets("CTC_Calculator_A1").Activate
  'ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123321"
  
  If Range("C2").Value >= 50000 Then `i need to move the range in down sell`
     Range("H2").Formula = "=ROUND(G2*50%,0)" `i need to move the range in down sell`

    Range("V2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K2").Select

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If


    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If


    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If
 
 Else: End If
  
  '--------------------------------------------------------------------
   If Range("C2").Value >= 27000 And Range("C2").Value <= 49999 Then
     Range("H2").Formula = "=ROUND(G2*50%,0)"

    Range("V2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K2").Select

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If


    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If


    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If
 
 Else: End If
 
 If Range("C2").Value <= 26999 Then
 
 Range("H2").Formula = "=ROUND(0,0)"
 Range("K2").Formula = "=ROUND(0,0)"
 
  
    Range("V2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H2").Select

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If

    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If


    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If


    If Range("Z2").Value <> 1 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Else: End If
 Else: End If
 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C2").Select
    'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123321"
End Sub


Before posting a question, please open your eyes and look what it looks like. Also, what are ranfance and proide? I think I fixed all the other spelling mistakes

The logic in the 1st and 2nd outer If statements is the same so you might as well remove the >=50000 one or fix what should be different. Please share why the same inner If statements are repeated 6 times. What is this Range("H2").Formula = "=ROUND(0,0)" supposed to do (compared to Range("H2").Value = 0)?

Hi there. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.
